# Webots ros2_control and controller_manager issue

Tags: gazebo, ros2, webots, controller-manager, ros2-control

I have been trying for the past week searching forums and documentation to solve this issue. I am trying to make a simple simulation using ros2 humble and webots 2023b. I had switched from Gazebo Fortress for the same issue, which tells me there's a bigger problem here.

My main issue is my *ros2_control* controllers (*joint_state_broadcaster* and *joint_trajectory_controller*) cannot seem to find the /controller_manager services no matter what I try. In my launch file, I currently:

1. Launch webots with *WebotsLauncher*
2. Spawn xacro robot with *URDFSpawner*
3. Start robot state publisher
4. **? Define robot driver with WebotsController**
5. **Fail to start joint state broadcaster spawner**

As far as I know #1, 2, 3 all succeed. I believe the issue lies somewhere with #5 not recognizing #4. *ros2 service list* does indeed show /controller_manager but only the following services and NOT load_controller, switch_controller, etc.

- /controller_manager/describe_parameters
- /controller_manager/get_parameter_types
- /controller_manager/get_parameters
- /controller_manager/list_parameters
- /controller_manager/set_parameters
- /controller_manager/set_parameters_atomically

And finally, this is the terminal output:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/hylander/.ros/log/2024-02-05-14-33-38-200142-laptop-ubeast-176480
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [webots-1]: process started with pid [176481]
[INFO] [ros2_supervisor.py-2]: process started with pid [176483]
[INFO] [ros2-3]: process started with pid [176486]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-4]: process started with pid [176489]
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process started with pid [176491]
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1707161618.404072091] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment 
[ros2_supervisor.py-2] The specified robot is not in the list of robots with <extern> controllers, retrying for another 50 seconds...
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1707161620.873216518] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[ros2_supervisor.py-2] [WARN] [1707161622.023178683] [Ros2Supervisor.Ros2Supervisor]: The URDF Spawner is deprecated. It will be replaced by a new PROTOSpawner in the future. See https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/issues/818 for more information.
[ros2_supervisor.py-2] [INFO] [1707161622.036303445] [Ros2Supervisor.Ros2Supervisor]: Ros2Supervisor has imported the URDF robot named "holonomic_robot".
[INFO] [webots_controller_holonomic_robot-6]: process started with pid [176582]
[INFO] [ros2-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 176486]
[webots_controller_holonomic_robot-6] [WARN] [1707161622.213335625] [holonomic_robot]: Passing robot description as a string is deprecated. Provide the URDF or Xacro file path instead.
[webots_controller_holonomic_robot-6] [INFO] [1707161622.219522904] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'WebotsControl' 
[webots_controller_holonomic_robot-6] [INFO] [1707161622.219577044] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'WebotsControl'
[webots_controller_holonomic_robot-6] [INFO] [1707161622.219614751] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'WebotsControl' 
[webots_controller_holonomic_robot-6] [INFO] [1707161622.219627495] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'WebotsControl'
[webots_controller_holonomic_robot-6] [INFO] [1707161622.219645453] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'WebotsControl' 
[webots_controller_holonomic_robot-6] [INFO] [1707161622.219655734] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'WebotsControl'
[webots_controller_holonomic_robot-6] [INFO] [1707161622.227259532] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[webots_controller_holonomic_robot-6] [WARN] [1707161622.227503154] [holonomic_robot]: Desired controller update period (100ms / 10Hz) is different from the Webots timestep (32ms). Please adjust the `update_rate` parameter in the `controller_manager` or the `basicTimeStep` parameter in the Webots `WorldInfo` node.
[webots_controller_holonomic_robot-6] [INFO] [1707161622.227621054] [holonomic_robot]: Controller successfully connected to robot in Webots simulation.
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1707161622.277857444] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1707161622.277915771] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment solid0
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1707161622.277921690] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment solid1
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1707161622.277926058] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment solid2
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1707161622.884433658] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
```

I didn't include the rest, because it just keeps searching for */controller_manager*. We can also see */controller_manager* subscribes to the */robot_description* topic successfully.

What could possibly be going on? I would seriously appreciate any help as I am at my wits end with this issue.

Here's my repo which is updated: https://github.com/hylander2126/webots_ros2_delta_rho

Comment: I haven't used webots, but what do you mean by _had switched from Gazebo Fortress for the same issue_?

Comment: @ChristophFroehlich I had the same issue in Gazebo and I initially thought it was due to ROS-Gazebo plugin issues, but now I've realized the problem has persisted in webots.

Comment: can you open a new question with the log from gazebo fortress? Or if you think it is related, please edit your initial question and add both logs.

Comment: This bug can be easily reproduced with the current version of webots-ros2-epuck (2023.1.1-2jammy.20240208.073726) and webots-ros2-turtlebot (2023.1.1-2jammy.20240208.073729). For example with ROS2 Iron: sudo apt install ros-iron-webots-ros2-epuck ros2 launch webots_ros2_epuck robot_launch.py Exactly the situation as described by hylander is the result: [spawner-8] [INFO] [1708372747.489308492] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available [spawner-7] [INFO] [1708372747.506219529] [spawner_diffdrive_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' s

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried building the webots_ros2 package from [sources](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Webots/Installation-Ubuntu.html)? I've been having the same problem with ros2 iron. Installing from sources solved it.

Here's the output I got when running your project. Didn't get any waiting message.

```
ros2 launch delta_rho webots_sim.launch.py

[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/irfan/.ros/log/2024-03-22-14-16-07-025666-Cornflour-45177
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [webots-1]: process started with pid [45180]
[INFO] [ros2_supervisor.py-2]: process started with pid [45182]
[INFO] [ros2-3]: process started with pid [45184]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-4]: process started with pid [45186]
[robot_state_publisher-4] [WARN] [1711095367.238432102] [kdl_parser]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1711095367.238550344] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1711095367.238656852] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment frontL
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1711095367.238674802] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment frontR
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1711095367.238688770] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment rear
[ros2_supervisor.py-2] The specified robot is not in the list of robots with <extern> controllers, retrying for another 50 seconds...
[ros2_supervisor.py-2] The specified robot is not in the list of robots with <extern> controllers, retrying for another 45 seconds...
[ros2_supervisor.py-2] [WARN] [1711095373.861136648] [Ros2Supervisor.Ros2Supervisor]: The URDF Spawner is deprecated. It will be replaced by a new PROTOSpawner in the future. See https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots_ros2/issues/818 for more information.
[ros2_supervisor.py-2] [INFO] [1711095373.888408469] [Ros2Supervisor.Ros2Supervisor]: Ros2Supervisor has imported the URDF robot named "holonomic_robot".
[INFO] [webots_controller_holonomic_robot-5]: process started with pid [45260]
[INFO] [ros2-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 45184]
[webots_controller_holonomic_robot-5] [WARN] [1711095374.273515583] [holonomic_robot]: Passing robot description as a string is deprecated. Provide the URDF or Xacro file path instead.
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1711095374.284431198] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1711095374.284527021] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment solid0
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1711095374.284558519] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment solid1
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1711095374.284586596] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment solid2
[webots_controller_holonomic_robot-5] [INFO] [1711095374.762440780] [holonomic_robot]: Controller successfully connected to robot in Webots simulation.
```